# ORDER_BY in codeigniter query builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to order the result based on status column tinyint(4) which is 0 and 1.

In this is query:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('status','DESC')->get('subjects');
```

The expected results are status with a of 1 first but the result query is still following the default database rows. How do I make it so that the status column should be descending?

[image]

Comment: I tried this and get your expected results. Is there any more to this query?

Comment: No, that is all apart from after querying I `return $query->result();`

Comment: I used tinyint(4) and everything, and the sort order is desc, gives 1, 0 just like you expect.

Comment: I am very sorry, it was a mistake on my part. My jquery data table is auto sorting a certain column. That's why.

Comment: hhahahaha, yes jquery datatable does that. i had experienced it also before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jquery data table is auto sorting a certain column. That's why.